# How do you parse an iOS push notification json payload in .Net Maui 7?

Tags: ios, json, apple-push-notifications, maui

I am making an assumption that the data is available in the WillPresentNotification event from the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate.

```
public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
{
    // Customize your handling of the notification here
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14, 0))
    {
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.List | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Banner | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
    }
    else
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
    }
}
```

Is it part of the 'UNNotification' object? If so how would you parse it? I don't see anything like 'payload' or 'json' etc. as a property.

Comment: Did you check the official document about [Create the JSON payload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification#2943359)? And what did the data mean? The `Alert`, `Sound` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Your data will be in  notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;
This will be a NSDictionary that you can extract information from by key.

basic example:

```
var userInfo = notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;

NSString sKey = new NSString("YourKey");
if (userInfo.ContainsKey(sKey))
    string myvalue = userInfo.ValueForKey(sKey).ToString();
```